# PostgreSQL : Find Postgresql database file on another drive and restore it

Tags: database, postgresql, data-recovery

I am working on a PostgreSQL database and recently we had a server upgrade, during which we changed our drive from a 2Tb raid Hard disk to a SSD. Now I mounted the RAID drive on a partition and can even access it.

Next what I would like to do is to get the database out of the mounted drive and restore it on the currently running PostgreSQL. How can I achieve this?

```
root@check03:/mnt/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/global# ls
11672      11674  11805  11809      11811  11813_fsm  11816  11820  11822  11824_fsm  11828  11916  11920        pg_internal.init
11672_fsm  11675  11807  11809_fsm  11812  11813_vm   11818  11820_fsm  11823  11824_vm   11829  11918  pg_control   pgstat.stat
11672_vm   11803  11808  11809_vm   11813  11815      11819  11820_vm   11824  11826      11914  11919  pg_filenode.map
root@check03:/mnt/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/global# cd ..
```

As you can see I am able to access the drives and the folders, but I don't know what to do next. Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the Postgres binaries must be the same version
- make sure that postgres is **not** running
- copy using `cp -rfp` or `tar | tar` or `cpio` , or whatever you like. Make sure you preserve the file owners and mode (top-level-directory must be 0700, owned by postgres)
- make sure that the postgres-startup (in /etc/init.d/postxxx) refers to the new directory; sometimes there is an environment variable $PGDATA contiaining the name of the postgres data directory; maybe you need to make changes to new_directory/postgres.conf, too (pg_log et al)
- for safety, **rename** the *old* data directory
- restart Postgres
- try to connect to it; check the logs.

---

Extra:

- Seasoned unix-administrators (like the BOFH ;-) might want to juggle with mountpoints and/or symlinks (instead of copying). Be my guest. YMMV
- Seasoned DBAs might want to create a tablespace, point it at the new location and (selectively) move databases, schemas or tables to the new location.

Comment: I used cp -R and copied the main directory itself. I am getting error  incomplete startup packet. What is the problem?

Comment: Either your copy was rotten or incomplete, or you copied the *hot* database files. Did you shutdown before copying?

Comment: I solved it by copying one file which was missing. I will accept your answer as I used cp -rfp, but before that, cp -rfp does not create any soft-links from the source to destination, right?

Comment: _LOG:  incomplete startup packet_ is not an error, it's an [inconsequential log](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Incomplete-startup-packet-help-needed-td5199030.html). Otherwise you'd see `ERROR` or `FATAL` instead of `LOG`.

Comment: It worked already, can you please answer the question I have asked in my comment before.

Answer (score 2):

You need the same version of PostgreSQL (9.1), also the same or later minor version. copy `main/` and everything below that to the new location. Copy the configuration of the old instance and adapt the paths to fit to the new location (the `main/` ist the ''data directory'' (also sometimes called `PGDATA`)). Start the new instance and look carefully at the logs. You should probably rebuild any indexes.

Also read about the [file layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-file-layout.html) in the fine documentation.

EDIT: If you have any chance to run the old configuration, read about [backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html), this is a much more safe way to transfer data.

Comment: It is the same version of PostgreSQL as the admin just took an image of the 2.0TB hd and put it in the SSD. I am taking a backup of main directory from the SSD first and planning to restore it with the the main folder from the 2.0TB hard disk. I presume that is correct.